# Search a keyword in multiple values using DropWizard and MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, dropwizard

I want to search a string in multiple values of all the MongoDB documents and return matched documents in return.

This is what I have tried to do it with one key

```
BasicDBObject object = new BasicDBObject();
object.put("firstName",  Pattern.compile(value));

FindIterable<Document> documents = mongoCollection.find(object)
         .skip(size*(index - 1)).limit(size);
for (Document document : documents) {
      customerList.add(CustomerMapper.map(document));
}
return customerList;
```

How can I change it to search a value in all key/values?

I have `firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber` in every document of the customers collection.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using following code:

```
BasicDBObject orQuery = new BasicDBObject();
List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
obj.add(new BasicDBObject("firstName", new BasicDBObject("$regex", value).append("$options", "i")));
obj.add(new BasicDBObject("lastName", new BasicDBObject("$regex", value).append("$options", "i")));
obj.add(new BasicDBObject("email", new BasicDBObject("$regex", value).append("$options", "i")));
obj.add(new BasicDBObject("phoneNumber", new BasicDBObject("$regex", value).append("$options", "i")));
orQuery.put("$or", obj);

FindIterable<Document> documents = mongoCollection.find(orQuery)
```

This helped me to use selected keys to use for searching.